# How to change the background color of QToolButton?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, button

I am looking to change the background color of a QToolButton. I want the shape of the button persevered along with the border. Only the background needs to change. I have tried working with the style sheet and all I get is a small section on the left and right margins with the color change.

I have been attempting to utilize this code snippet:

```
class ColorButton : public QToolButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ColorButton(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QToolButton(parent) {}
protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override
    {
        QStylePainter p(this);
        QStyleOptionToolButton opt;
        initStyleOption(&opt);
        p.drawComplexControl(QStyle::CC_ToolButton,   opt);
        p.setBrush(QColor(255,0,0,100));
        p.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
        p.drawRect(4,4,width()-8,height()-8);
    }
};
```

However, all I get is a red rectangle colored red that is drawn on top of the text. This mostly works however, the text now was a red tint to it.

Basically, all I need and want is to be able to change the background color. If I use the provided snippet, I would need to figure out how I can force draw the text as the foreground.

Or if there is a better way then please let me know!

Thank you.

Edit:

I am running Qt 5.9 on the latest version of Linux Mint (as of this writing)

Edit 2:

I should also note that I have attempted using the QPalette to change the color. This did not work. Sample code posted:

```
    p_deactiveColor.setBrush(QPalette::Base, QColor(Qt::red));
    p_deactiveColor.setBrush(QPalette::Button, QColor(Qt::red));
    p_deactiveColor.setBrush(QPalette::Window, QColor(Qt::red));
    p_deactiveColor.setBrush(QPalette::WindowText, QColor(Qt::red));

    p_activeColor.setBrush(QPalette::Base, QColor(Qt::green));
    p_activeColor.setBrush(QPalette::Button, QColor(Qt::green));

    ui->cupExtendButton->setPalette(p_deactiveColor);
```

Please note, I tried various combinations of the `p_deactiveColor.setBrush` function. I posted the various settings that I edited here. Non of the combinations worked

Comment: Perhaps this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

Comment: @drescherjm Right so there is this CSS code: `QPushButton { background-color: red; border: none; }` however, I want to use the native border and only change the background color. So using the stylesheet is not a valid solution.

Comment: What about `QPushButton { background-color: red; }`

Comment: I tried that and there is a bug in Qt where you need to include the border property for it to display properly. I am looking for a work around to this since I want to keep the original border. If I only do the 'QPushButton { background-color: red; }' then only the left and right margins will change colors