# Text on QToolButton not being drawn

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, button

This is a follow up question to this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57045926/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-qtoolbutton?noredirect=1#comment100682814_57045926).

I am trying a method where I subclass the QToolButton and override the paint event such that a red rectangle is drawn first and the text is drawn on top of the rectangle.

I have the code mostly working, however, the text on the button is not being drawn. I have looked at a few forum posting but not much has panned out. Below is the current version of the paint override function:

```
virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override
{
    QString tempText;
    QStylePainter p(this);
    QStyleOptionToolButton opt;
    initStyleOption(&opt);
    tempText = opt.text;
    opt.text = QString();
    p.save();
    p.drawComplexControl(QStyle::CC_ToolButton, opt);
    p.setBrush(QColor(255,0,0,100));
    p.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    p.drawRect(4,4,width()-8,height()-8);

    // p.setBrush(QColor(0,0,0));
    p.setPen(QColor(0,0,0));

    p.setFont(this->font());

    p.drawText(this->frameGeometry(), Qt::AlignCenter, tempText);
    p.restore();
}
```

Currently, the logic of the code should be:

1) Save the text contained in `opt` (This text is drawn on the button). In my code, the text in `opt` is saved in a variable called `tempText`

2) Set `opt.text` to an empty string

3) Draw the button with the red rectangle in the middle

4) Draw `tempText` on the button with the proper alignment settings. For this, I was thinking about bounding the text to a frame within the button. But so far, there is no text drawn on the button.

Comment: Note that [`QWidget::frameGeometry`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#frameGeometry-prop) returns the `"geometry of the widget relative to its parent..."`.  Are you sure you shouldn't be using [`QWidget::contentsRect`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contentsRect) instead?

Comment: @G.M. Aw man, that was it, I feel silly now. It is ok, learned something new today! Post it as a solution and I will accept it! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment, [`QWidget::frameGeometry`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#frameGeometry-prop) returns the...

> "geometry of the widget relative to its parent..."

which isn't actually what you want here.  Rather you want the `QRect` in which the contents of the `QWidget` will be rendered.  So you probably want...

```
p.drawText(contentsRect(), Qt::AlignCenter, tempText);
```

---

On a separate note, your `paintEvent` implementation calls `QPainter::save` and `QPainter::restore`.  Those are potentially expensive operations and should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.